# Correlation between Sin and Square wave

Tags: frequency, correlation

I would like to know how $\frac T2$ came for time period in the image below.Because I think the frequncy is 1 so time period should be 1.Is that correct? or can anyone help me.[image].

The article from where I got this image is [here](http://1drv.ms/1xJ4Rs8)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the second half of the period of the sinusoid is simply equal to the first half times $-1$. Since the same is true for the square wave, the multiplication of the two is the same in both intervals $[0,T/2]$ and $[T/2,T]$. That's why the integral over the whole period equals twice the integral over the first half of the period.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer.But could you say how it becomes "part times -1".

Comment: @justin: What I meant to say was that the second half of the period of the sine wave equals the inverted first half.

Comment: :okay.Then whether time period should become $T$.Whether we are only taking the integral over the first half of the signal(that means upto 0.5 second)?In that case it's right it should be $\frac T2$.I couldn't get why we should express timeperiod in $T$ when the timeperiod is given in numbers in the image.

Comment: @justin: Draw $x(t)y(t)$ in the interval $[0,T]$, and you'll understand.

Comment: @justin: in case it helps: the first line in the correlation calculation is generic: it works for any value of $T$. In the second line, they substitute $T$ with 1 to get the value of the correlation in the particular case when $T=1$.

Comment: @MBaz:Thanks for your comment.Okay now I got why we are using $T$ instead of numbers but as Matt L. told if we have to calculate the integral in $[0,T]$ then could you say how $\frac T2$ would come because I think $T$ should come for time period.

Comment: @justin: The function to be integrated is the same in the interval $[0,T/2]$ and in the interval $[T/2,T]$, so instead of integrating from $0$ to $T$ you can as well integrate from $0$ to $T/2$ and multiply by $2$.

Comment: @MattL.:okay.But have they done the multiplication of two in the image?

Comment: @justin: Yes, they divide by $T/2$ instead of by $T$. This gives you a factor of 2.

Comment: @MattL.:That's right.But could you explain how the the function is same in $[0,\frac T2]$ and $[\frac T2,T]$.Because I think that the value in the first half i.e upto $\frac T2$ is positive while the other half upto $T$ is negative.

Comment: @justin: *Both* functions that are multiplied (the sine and the rectangle) are positive in the first half, and *both* are negative in the second half. Since 'negative times negative' is positive, both are the same in both intervals.

Comment: @MattL.:Okay I got why we should take from 0 to $\frac T2$ but could you say where they have multiplied by two in the image?I can ony see they have divided by a factor of $\frac T2$ but that's essential because when we take upto $\frac T2$ as the time we have to divide by that time so $T$ is replaced with $\frac T2$.

Comment: @justin: $1/(T/2)=2/T$ which is twice the factor they used before ($1/T$).

Comment: @MattL.:But isn't that right to represent $\frac T2$ instead of $T$ as time period since we integrate from 0 to $\frac T2$for the image or are we still taking time period as $T$ and just multiplying the integral by 2.

Comment: @justin: You just try to evaluate the first integral on the left-hand side. Don't think of changing periods or anything else, the first integral is just simplified, that's it.

Comment: @MattL.:okay.Now I got it.Did you meant to say that there is no need in substituting $T$ with $\frac T2$ in integration since T is a constant?

Comment: @justin: There is no substitution, they just simplify and solve the original integral.

Comment: @MattL.:I really meant the substitution while doing integration.