# correlation coefficient between these two signals

Tags: correlation

[image]

hello there

can anyone tell me how to find correlation coefficient between these two signal using equation??
i don't know how to find correlation coefficient between these two signals.

i checked this link
[Correlation between Sin and Square wave](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19263/correlation-between-sin-and-square-wave)
but i can't find solution

Comment: What happens if you apply the formula?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any attempt to apply the formula known to OP, and thus, neither is a valid, clear, question, nor holds any value for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt mentioned in the comment you could have applied the formula.
Correlation coefficient is given be integrating x(t)*y(t) over a time period T.
and dividing by time period T.Here x(t) = 1 and y(t) = sin(2*pi*t). So you have to integrate sine signal over a time period 2pi which results in 0.